# problem with where condition in sqlAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

when I use the following select statement
`statement = select(Machine).join(Machine.drive_standards_ref).where(Asso_Tables.serie_FPK== series)`
do the where condition does not work when we enter values for a series then we will get both them where it is true and when it is false.

here is a some code that I have made to test it

```
from typing import Optional, List

from sqlalchemy import select, create_engine, ForeignKey, String, DECIMAL
from sqlalchemy.exc import PendingRollbackError
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, Session

user = "xxxx"

servername = "XXXX"
database = "xxxx"
driver = "ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
engine = create_engine(
    f"mssql+pyodbc://@{servername}/{database}?MARS_Connection=Yes&trusted_connection=yes&driver={driver}")

engine.connect()

session = Session(bind=engine)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass
class Asso_Tables(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Asso_Tables"

    catalog_no_FPK: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("Machine.catalog_no_PK"), primary_key=True)
    serie_FPK: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("Serie.serie_PK"), primary_key=True)
    some_other_data: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True)


class Machine(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Machine"

    catalog_no_PK: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(25), primary_key=True)

    drive_standards_ref: Mapped[List["Asso_Tables"]] = relationship()

class Serie(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Serie"
    serie_PK: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(25),primary_key=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def get_servo_motors_with_actual_series_data(series: str) -> List[Machine] | None:
    statement = select(Machine).join(Machine.drive_standards_ref).where(Asso_Tables.serie_FPK== series)
    try:
        return session.scalars(statement).all()
    except PendingRollbackError:
        session.rollback()
    return session.scalars(statement).all()

session.add(Serie(serie_PK="test1"))
session.commit()
session.add(Serie(serie_PK="test10"))
session.commit()

session.add(Machine(catalog_no_PK="1"))
session.commit()
session.add(Asso_Tables(catalog_no_FPK="1",serie_FPK="test1"))
session.commit()
session.add(Asso_Tables(catalog_no_FPK="1",serie_FPK="test10"))
session.commit()

test = get_servo_motors_with_actual_series_data("test1")
print(len(test.drive_standards_ref)==2) #we assummed that it was 1
```

we are using Python 3.11 SQLALchemy 2.023 pyodbc 5.0.1

I have tried many different thing I have reproduced it as the code as you can see above tried to rename serie_FPK tried to enter the series manual.
I have also looked at the SQL Queries and compared it with other places we have used it in our code. I have even tried to enter the SQL Query in SSMS (and changed the things that was needed) where I got the expected result.
So I am at a lost

Comment: I'm not sure if you figured this out but I feel like some code is missing.  Can you explain what is printed versus what you expect to be printed?  Aslo you could turn `echo=True` on the engine and include the actual SQL executed and how it differs from what you expected.

Comment: I have just change to make it more clearly what we expected and what we got. 
It was also a good idea of using echo this has meant that I was able to locate the problem. That was that I misunderstood what it did I had assumed that it would make an object based on the join not a  "pointer" to the object in the database. Do you have any idea of how to make it soo that it will return an object with all the join statement?